# Why is my ReactJS D3 scatter plot breaking on mouse enter and how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, d3.js, react-hooks

The visualization renders just fine but breaks as soon as I mouse over one of the circles.

[Viz in Codepen](https://codepen.io/dr_rompecabezas/pen/NWpbogq)

Console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: d.Time.substring is not a function
```

The following is the block that's triggering the error from within the parent (App) component. The purpose of this block is to mutate the fetched data so that I can use a date object to build the yScale using D3's scaleTime. This works, until, it seems, a state change is triggered by the mouse event.

```
  console.log(data[0].Time); // Returns "36:50"

  data.forEach((d) => {
    let minutes = d.Time.substring(0, 2);
    let seconds = d.Time.substring(3);
    d.Time = new Date(1976, 6, 28, 0, minutes, seconds);
  });

  console.log(data[0].Time); // Returns Date Wed Jul 28 1976 00:36:50 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

It would seem to me I only need to run this code once, when the data loads, but I haven't figured out how to do that. I tried adding it to the useEffect hook that's fetching the JSON data, but I couldn't figure out how to this. I found many examples for csv files (using the row argument) but none so far for parsing json files within the useEffect Hook that fetches the data. When I try to just run the function above after the D3 fetch, data in state is still null (default state).

This is how I fetch the data:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    d3.json(url).then((json) => {
      setData(json);
    });
  }, []);
```

This is entire code for the App component:

```
// App Parent Component
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [hoveredValue, setHoveredValue] = useState(null);
  const [mousePosition, setMousePosition] = useState(initialMousePosition);

  useEffect(() => {
    d3.json(url).then((json) => {
      setData(json);
    });
  }, []);

  const handleMouseMove = useCallback(
    (event) => {
      const { clientX, clientY } = event;
      setMousePosition({ x: clientX, y: clientY });
    },
    [setMousePosition]
  );

  if (!data) {
    return <pre>Loading...</pre>;
  }

  console.log(data[0].Time); // Returns "36:50"

  data.forEach((d) => {
    let minutes = d.Time.substring(0, 2);
    let seconds = d.Time.substring(3);
    d.Time = new Date(1976, 6, 28, 0, minutes, seconds);
  });

  console.log(data[0].Time); // Returns Date Wed Jul 28 1976 00:36:50 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

  const xValue = (d) => d.Year;
  const leftAxisLabel = "Time in minutes";

  const yValue = (d) => d.Time;
  const bottomAxisLabel = "Year";
  const yAxisTickFormat = d3.timeFormat("%M:%S");

  const xScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, xValue))
    .range([0, innerWidth])
    .nice();

  const yScale = d3
    .scaleTime()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, yValue))
    .range([0, innerHeight])
    .nice();

  return (
    <div>
      <Tooltip hoveredValue={hoveredValue} mousePosition={mousePosition} />
      <div id="viz-container">
        <div id="title">{titleLabel}</div>
        <div id="subtitle">{subtitleLabel}</div>
        <div id="left-axis-label">{leftAxisLabel}</div>
        <div id="bottom-axis-label">{bottomAxisLabel}</div>
        <Legend innerWidth={innerWidth} innerHeight={innerHeight} />
        <svg id="svg" width={width} height={height}>
          <g transform={`translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`}>
            <g id="y-axis" className="y-axis">
              <AxisLeft
                yScale={yScale}
                innerWidth={innerWidth}
                yAxisTickFormat={yAxisTickFormat}
                tickOffset={20}
              />
            </g>
            <g id="x-axis" className="x-axis">
              <AxisBottom
                xScale={xScale}
                innerHeight={innerHeight}
                tickOffset={8}
              />
            </g>
            <Marks
              data={data}
              xScale={xScale}
              xValue={xValue}
              yScale={yScale}
              yValue={yValue}
              setHoveredValue={setHoveredValue}
              handleMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
            />
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And this is the child component that renders the circles that I want to be able to mouse over (to display a tooltip):

```
// Marks (Dots) Component
const Marks = ({
  data,
  xScale,
  xValue,
  yScale,
  yValue,
  setHoveredValue,
  handleMouseMove
}) =>
  data.map((d, i) => (
    <>
      <circle
        key={data[i].Place}
        data-xvalue={xValue(d)}
        data-yvalue={yValue(d)}
        className="dot"
        cx={xScale(xValue(d))}
        cy={yScale(yValue(d))}
        r="7"
        fill={data[i].Doping ? "#FF4500" : "#228C22"}
        opacity="0.7"
        onMouseEnter={() => setHoveredValue([0, 0])} // Set to [xValue(d), yValue(d)] after debugging
        onMouseLeave={() => setHoveredValue(null)}
        onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
      />
    </>
  ));
```

This is my first time posting to Stack Overflow. Apologies for any etiquette rules I may have broken, and thank you very much for any help, including links to self-help documentation.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution I can see is to add a check in the forEach that `d.Time` exists before proceeding, for some reason, data seems to have a different item in the array than the expected, as Time property doesnt exists or is not a string at least.

Very probable your `setData(json);` in the useEffect needs to parse the json `setData(JSON.parse(json));`

Comment: I wrapped the block in a conditional statement as you suggested and it didn't prevent the error. The data is parsed adequately by the `d3.json` function. The `d.Time` block is mutating the data after it has been fetched. Without the mouse event, the data fetch would be the only time the state is changed. It seems the state change triggered by the mouse event causes this block to run again unnecessarily. I only need to mutate the data once when fetched. Any ideas on how to move this block of code to useEffect hook so it runs only once after the fetch?

Comment: take out the console.logs as probably fails there, and you can of course move that forEach into the success just before of setting the data

Comment: I believe I did as you said, but the data does not load. Am I missing some syntax? [Screenshot] (https://www.screencast.com/t/5NKfVgnjYb).

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to manjupillai16 at freeCodeCamp for the two [solutions](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/d3-scatter-plot-breaks-on-mouse-events-reactjs-hooks/460989) provided.

The problem was that any state change that triggered a re-render would run the forEach block again, only the data had been mutated to a date object from the fetched string.

Here's the solution with useEffect:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      data.forEach((d) => {
        let minutes = d.Time.substring(0, 2);
        let seconds = d.Time.substring(3);
        d.Time = new Date(1976, 6, 28, 0, minutes, seconds);
      });
      setLoaded(true);
    }
  }, [data]);
```

And here's the solution using a conditional statement to skip the block after the data had been mutated:

```
  if (typeof data[0].Time === "string") {
    data.forEach((d) => {
      let minutes = d.Time.substring(0, 2);
      let seconds = d.Time.substring(3);
      d.Time = new Date(1976, 6, 28, 0, minutes, seconds);
    });
  }
```